# Install-free app to get mobo model + Windows version?

Tags: windows

I need users to send information about their PC, including hardware (motherboard model) and software (Windows version, including SP + .Net).

Ideally, I'd like to get this information through a web browser so they don't need to install anything. Second best would be a single EXE, ie. installer-free app, that they just need to download on their Deskop and run.

The following either use an installer or come as a ZIP file (both are too complicated for my users):

```
www.cpuid.com
www.belarc.com
Everest www.lavalys.com/products
```

Thank you.

Comment: A 'click Yes four times and accept license terms' installer is too complicated for your users?  I do not envy your position, sir/madam.

Comment: But then, there are more dumb users than smart ones, hence bigger opportunities. Just look at Apple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) can do this for you, File -> Publish Snapshot allows me to show you [an example of my system](http://speccy.piriform.com/results/hZPrc8OzXPdozyrlCMlGG2M).

The .NET version they at least have can be determined by their Windows version,
maybe we could ask the Speccy developers to include this information too...

You could use [.NET version Check](http://www.tmgdevelopment.co.uk/versioncheck.htm) for that, it does not need .NET to run.

Comment: @TomWj - May not work for him since he doesn't want his users to need to use an installer...also nice PC specs :)

Comment: Speccy is portable, thus a single exe: http://www.piriform.com/speccy/download/portable

Comment: Looks like it also needs to be run under an admin account, which may or may not be an issue.  It is def. portable though!

Comment: JNK: It's a laptop, as I use it a lot I went for a Full HD gaming one...

Comment: Thanks much for the link on Speccy. It's pretty close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This may be easy for ya:

Make a batch file they can run which outputs it to a .txt file they can send to  you.

```
c:
cd\
systeminfo >Sysinfo.txt
Dir c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v*.* >> Sysinfo.txt
```

Then you have a .txt in the root of C: that has everything you need in it.

Comment: You could also write it to %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Sysinfo.txt

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be possible for a webpage to display hardware information without using some ActiveX browser plugin.

I think your best bet is to just tell your users to type 'msinfo32.exe' into either the Start Menu search for or Explorer address bar, and explain how they can send you the exported information file.

Comment: MSInfo32 is Vista/7 only.

Comment: No it's not - it came with XP. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308549

Comment: Actually it even came with Office '97 and was included with Windows 2000 as well.

Comment: Apologies, I was wrong.  It just doesn't work from a cmd prompt.